# Why didn't trigger the CellEndEdit event of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

All,I knew we can set a column editable for a `DataGridView`.
And when finish editing the cell. the `CellEndEdit` event would be triggered.
But I just want to know why didn't end the edit of cell when I click the blank area of `DataGridView`. And click the area out of `DataGridView` doesn't trigger it too. only clicking the other cells could make it happen. It really doesn't make sense. Could anyone know why ? and How to make it ? It try to use the Click event of the `DataGridView`, But When I click the cell, It also trigger the `DataGridView_click` event.

```
    private void dgvList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dgvFileList.EndEdit();

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the HitTest function in the MouseDown event of the grid:

```
void dgvFileList_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgvFileList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
  if (hit.RowIndex < 0 | hit.ColumnIndex < 0) {
    dgvFileList.EndEdit();
  }
}
```

Clicking outside the DataGridView control would require hitting a focusable control.

Comment: Wow...I never heard it before. What bother me is I can't tell the cell click and grid click event. Now I am happy with it! Thank you . man

Comment: I will also implement Form_Click Event to `EndEdit`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before `BeginEdit`. Set a variable to identify if current state is edit mode.

```
bBeginEdit = true;
dgvFileList.BeginEdit(false);
```

In the Form_Click event

```
        if (bBeginEdit)
        {
            dgvFileList.EndEdit();
            bBeginEdit = false;
        }
```

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

CellEndEdit() causes the event to be fired only if the cell was in edit mode (see Joe.wang's response). You can simply preceed CellEndEdit() with CellBeginEdit() to enter Edit mode (code from CellContentClick-handler, PickNewFont() is a wrapper for the FontDialog):

```
[...]
else if (String.Compare(rowName, "Font name") == 0)    // user clicks on Font-row
{
    dgvConfigSettings.BeginEdit(true);
    Font newFont = PickNewFont(fontName, fontSize, fontStyle);
    dgvConfigSettings.CurrentCell.Tag = newFont;    // a bit dirty.... but that way we can pick-up the font in the panel-handler more easily
    dgvConfigSettings.CurrentCell.Value = newFont.Name.ToString();
    dgvConfigSettings.EndEdit();
}
```