# In datagridview (vb.net) the RowLeave fires before the CellEndEdit in the last cell of the row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datarow

There is a similar question here [Why didn't trigger the CellEndEdit event of DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267871/why-didnt-trigger-the-cellendedit-event-of-datagridview) so please don't tell me it was already answered.  :-)  That solution addresses clicking out of the grid, not tabbing out of the last cell in the row.

I am entering data into a new row in a datagridview.  When I leave the row I check to see if the row is new.  If it is a new row, I add the data to the database.  However, when I tab out of the last cell, the RowLeave fires and the last cell in the row is empty.  The other cells show data but not the last one.

I verified that the LeaveRow fires before CellEndEdit when tabbing out of the last field.

If I enter data in the last cell and click the previous cell, THEN leave the row, it captures the data from the last cell.

How can I force the value I enter in the last cell to be saved BEFORE the RowLeave event fires?  I am saving the new row in the RowLeave event.

Here is a the code for the RowLeave event

```
Private Sub dgVisa_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgVisa.RowLeave

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgVisa.CurrentRow

    If dgVisa.IsCurrentRowDirty Then

        MsgBox(row.Cells(0).FormattedValue)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(2).FormattedValue)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(3).FormattedValue)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(4).FormattedValue)
        MsgBox(row.Cells(5).FormattedValue)


        If gbolUserAddedRow = True Then

            Dim AddRecord As New GetMSCADPaymentDetailsTableAdapters.uspMSGetMSCADBankDetailsByCreditCardTypeIdentTableAdapter

            AddRecord.Insert(#9/1/2018#,
                             1,
                             5,
                             1,
                             4)

            AddRecord.Insert(CDate(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue),
                             1,
                             CDbl(row.Cells(3).FormattedValue),
                             CDbl(row.Cells(4).FormattedValue),
                             CDbl(row.Cells(5).FormattedValue))

            gbolUserAddedRow = False


        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is just a workaround, but I did pick up something from the other question that fixes the issue.

I put dgVisa.EndEdit() at the beginning of the code shown above.  It forces the EndCellEdit to fire before the rest of the code.

If anyone has a more graceful answer let me know.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: I was just about to post this, but you figured most of it out.  `If dgVisa.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then dgVisa.EndEdit()`